# How to make sure NaNs propagate when using SSE intrinsics?

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, sse, nan

I recently read this about `NaN` values in SSE arithmetic operations:

> The result of arithmetic operations acting on two not a number (NAN) arguments is undefined. Therefore, floating-point operations using NAN arguments will not match the expected behavior of the corresponding assembly instructions.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5c07e2a(v=vs.100).aspx

Does this mean that, say, adding two `__m128` values might convert a `NaN` to a real?

If a calculation relied on a `NaN` value, I need the final result to be `NaN` as well. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I think it's being overly pedantic. Floating-point SSE instructions should follow IEEE floating-point behavior rather strictly unless you do stuff like flush denormals or something of that sort.

Comment: @Mysticial: It is not saying SSE instructions will not provide the expected results. It is saying the compiler might not use SSE instructions to implement SSE-like intrinsics.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I see what you're saying. But to date I have yet to see something like that happen. So I'm not entirely convinced of it.

Comment: @Mysticial: It is imprudent to ignore documentation that says results are not guaranteed.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'm not gonna imply that it's the case here, but MSDN documentation has been known to have errors before. (And as a result, I always take even official documentation with a grain of salt.) So I wouldn't be at all surprised that the person who wrote that snippet is probably less informed about the topic than we are.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Alright look. As you clearly have nothing else constructive to say, I will end with one final comment. I don't question official documentation easily. But when I do, it's because I have good reason to. Given my knowledge and experience with compilers, SSE intrinsics/instructions, and how they are implemented, I can say that this quoted statement about NaNs is pretty farfetched (not impossible, but farfetched). Perhaps it only applies in very niche corner cases - in which they should clarify those and not leave us guessing at all the "safe" cases which the majority of us use

Comment: @EricPostpischil Of course results aren't guaranteed; when was the last time you saw software that *wasn't* provided "with no warranty of any kind"?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'm quite sure the OP's code would not be the first to break if Microsoft ever decided to take advantage of the officially "undefined behavior" of NaNs with their intrinsics: the entire point of NaN is to avoid the need to check for an error condition all the time, and even if Microsoft for some reason wants to keep the option open to have non-strictly-conforming NaN behavior in the future for whatever reason, they are unlikely to do anything that would break the code of 99% of their users (especially given their focus on backward compatibility)

Comment: @Inverse (note that I wouldn't depend on this behavior if my life depended on it, but you shouldn't be depending on the behavior of any Microsoft product in that case anyway)

Comment: @EricPostpischil You're really gaining momentum, aren't you? Your reactions in this discussion speak more to your character than your claimed age.

Comment: @ChristianRau: I stand by my position that no amount of “knowledge”, wishful thinking, or experience can provide a guarantee of behavior when the documentation clearly says the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Indeed a valid point (upvoted your answer anyway).

Comment: @EricPostpischil I don't know what OP's use case is "I need the final result to be `NaN` as well" means someone's life is on the line, then of course he shouldn't rely on that (but he shouldn't rely on much anyway at that point). The argument is simply that dropping completely down to assembly just to avoid illogically undefined NaN behavior is not (generally) practical and defeats both the purpose of having intrinsics and NaNs in the general. Of course, he should test to see what the actual behavior is, but if it works, it's just a practical risk/return calculation whether to rely on it.

Comment: @StephenLin: First, you mean “dropping down to SSE instructions”, not “intrinsics”. The issue here is that the compiler provides intrinsics but does not guarantee they map to SSE instructions. Second, you cannot test to see what the actual behavior is; there are infinitely many elements in the source code set accepted by the compiler, and no finite set of tests can determine the behavior for the entire set. Third, correct software is important in many situations, not just when human life is at risk. None of the assumptions here about dismissing the documentation are supported.

Comment: @EricPostpischil There's almost no existent large codebase out there that doesn't rely on something that an implementation has left undefined or murkily defined. And in any case, the variance caused by possible bugs in his code or the the implementation is probably larger than the expected variance from this purportedly "undefined" behavior. This is what testing is for.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, that's "intrinsics" instead of "assembly instructions" was a typo that I corrected. the point is, you don't have any guarantee of any of that anyway, so you need tests if that's important.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It's just not black and white, that's all. Plenty of low-level C and C++ code takes advantage of ABI implementation details that can change in any future compiler version for performance, which is fine if you really need the performance, you know what you're exposed to, and you have proper testing. You should never upgrade your compiler without full regression testing anyway.

Comment: @StephenLin: There is no merit in reasoning that people do some bad things, therefore other bad things are okay.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It's bad to assume anything, regardless of what documentation says or doesn't say. If something's important to you, you make sure it's tested.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Anyone using MSVC++ for anything non-trivial is 99% likely to be unexpectedly relying on Microsoft-specific behavior that is undefined or unspecified by the documentation anyway, unless they're cross compiling all the time. If absolute correctness is required, you shouldn't be going the route of using a closed-source compiler that is (mostly) poorly documented. If you have to anyway, then you should test everything no matter what the documentation says.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I interpret that text, what it is saying is that the compiler offers various intrinsics which roughly correspond to SSE instructions. Generally, you can expect that the compiler will use SSE instructions to implement the intrinsics. However, this is not strict. The intrinsics actually specify operations in some abstract model of computation; they do not specify SSE instructions directly. In that abstract model, the result of operating on two NaNs (odd that it does not seem to allow for one NaN and one number) is undefined. Therefore, the result you get from, for example, adding two NaNs might not be a NaN.

In particular, operations in the abstract model would be subject to compiler optimizations, and those optimizations might result in things other than SSE instructions (calculations at compile time, omitted instructions if the compiler can deduce that NaNs are present so it does not need to actually perform an add, et cetera).

It seems that if you want to guarantee the semantics specified for SSE instructions, you might have to write in assembly language rather than using intrinsics in Microsoft’s compiler.

I do wish vendors would stop giving short shrift to floating-point semantics. It is difficult to do engineering in the absence of well-specified behavior.

Comment: There is one relatively benign possibility. It might always produce a NaN, but not necessarily one that relates in any consistent fashion to the input NaNs. If that is the case, it would be helpful to have it documented.

Comment: This sounds like it could only be a problem if two values could be proven by the compiler to be `NaN` and there was a compelling reason for the compiler to take advantage of it, imho: the former of which doesn't seem likely and the latter of which is hard to come up with an example of...

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: That seems likely. Which of two input NaNs an instruction returns often depends on operand order, and the compiler may well not preserve order from intrinsics to instructions. That would lead to a need to document that which of two NaNs is returned is undefined, and sloppy handling of that could result in documentation stating that the result of operating on two NaNs is undefined. Nonetheless, the documentation says what it says.

Comment: I find it bizarre that many languages won't allow a `double` to be converted to a `float` without an explicit cast, but will willy-nilly promote things to `double` internally and then cast back.  If I were designing a language, I would have "IEEE single" and "IEEE double" types whose semantics would behave exactly according to IEEE standards, and other 32-bit and 64-bit float types with more helpful semantics (e.g. having `==` implement an equivalence relation in cases where it compiles, having a 32-bit type which would evaluate f1=(f2+f3+f4)` using 64-bit intermediate results, etc.)