# Replace NaN with last non-NaN value

Tags: matlab, replace, nan

I have a matrix with several NaN values and I want to replace those with the last non-NaN value. The matrix is very large so ideally I would do it in a vectorized fashion.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
M = [
NaN NaN NaN 3
7   NaN NaN 1
NaN NaN NaN 9
NaN 6   NaN NaN
NaN NaN NaN NaN
8   NaN NaN 8
NaN 5   NaN NaN
NaN NaN NaN NaN
9   NaN NaN NaN]
```

And the output should be:

```
Out = [
NaN NaN NaN 3
7   NaN NaN 1
7   NaN NaN 9
7   6   NaN 9
7   6   NaN 9
8   6   NaN 8
8   5   NaN 8
8   5   NaN 8
9   5   NaN 8]
```

I was wondering whether anyone faced a similar problem and knows an efficient way to solve it. I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17240194/speed-up-replace-nans-with-last-non-nan-value) similar post but all solutions seem to involve a `for` loop.

Comment: Why are you only replacing some `NaN`s and not others? Is this per column? Per row? Per something else?

Comment: Sorry. It was a typo. I have corrected it. It is per column.

Comment: I doubt this is possible, I don't think NAN is probably handled by vectorized functions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15560567/how-to-make-sure-nans-propagate-when-using-sse-intrinsics

Comment: Well the NaNs can be replaced by any arbitrary number such as -99

Comment: I'm still not understanding columns 1 and 2 of your desired output.

Comment: @excaza he replaces all NaNs after the first non-nan input with the first non-nan input and after the 2nd non-nan input he replaces all nans with the 2nd non-nan input and so on. and he does that column-wise.

Comment: First column starts with NaN. That keeps as is. Then there is a seven. All subsequent NaN values get replaced with seven. Until you get the eight. All subsequent NaN get replaced with NaN. Until you get the 9.

Comment: Try inpainting methods which fill the missing data with neighbors. Here is function at fileexchange : https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4551-inpaint-nans

Comment: Do the values  have a known range? Example, only values 0-9 are allowed or can they be anything?

Comment: They must be greater than zero. If negative they are for sure -0.01.
So within these criteria they can be anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one vectorized approach -

```
mask = ~isnan(M);
cumsums = cumsum(mask,1);
invalid_mask = cumsums==0;
cumsums(invalid_mask) = 1;

shifts = [0 cumsum(sum(mask(:,1:end-1),1))];

idx = bsxfun(@plus,cumsums, shifts);
nums = M(mask);
out = nums(idx);
out(invalid_mask)=nan;
```

Comment: Impressive! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [`fillmissing`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fillmissing.html) function if you have R2016b or beyond.  You can use the `'previous'` method to do exactly this.